# How do you generate a string which has a user defined length?

Tags: android, string

I need to be able to generate strings with a user defined length.
For example, if the user enters 128, I need a string with 128 characters. 
Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create X random `char`s (in a loop) and use a `StringBuffer` to concatenate them

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. I wasn't aware of StringBuffer and because of your suggestion I discovered StringBuilder which is better suited for my task. Cheers again.

Comment: @AlexHaycock you probably won't need `StringBuffer` since it's synchronized to be thread-safe... maybe you want `StringBuilder`? Either way you can just use `char[]` as in my example :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
static final String generate(int n) {
  final char[] buf = new char[n];
  final Random rand = new Random();
  final int n_cs = Character.MAX_VALUE + 1;
  while (n > 0) {
    char ch;
    do {
      ch = (char) rand.nextInt(n_cs);
    } while (Character.isHighSurrogate(ch)
               || Character.isLowSurrogate(ch));
    buf[--n] = ch;
  }
  return new String(buf);
}
```

Generally, you should probably specify some sort of alphabet, as follows...

```
static final String generate(int n, final char[] alphabet) {
  final char[] buf = new char[n];
  final Random rand = new Random();
  final int n_alpha = alphabet.length;
  while (n > 0) {
    buf[--n] = alphabet[rand.nextInt(n_alpha)];
  }
  return new String(buf);
}
```